# How to handle long selections: Dropdown or Select option?

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I’m developing a web app. At checkout, logged in users can select one of their saved shipping addresses.
On address selection, Javascript will populate the input fields.

Whats the best method a dropdown or select option tag or something else?

Comment: How many addresses are they likely to have?

Comment: Varies user to user but typical <10.

Comment: Then I would suggest a select list (dropdown).  If it were no more than two or three, I would have suggested radio buttons.  Presumably, you have the addresses in an array, or something like that, with a unique identifier for each address?

Comment: Makes sense and yes the addresses are in an array.

Comment: OK - then a select list is best as it is easiest to load from an array.  It also keeps the page easier to use from a user's perspective.  You should ensure that one address is pre-selected in case the user forgets to pick an alternative and the select list should be labelled as something like "Change shipping address" rather than "Pick shipping address"

Comment: What I struggle to see is if it is ideal to fit an entire address inside the select option tag. Wouldn’t I need divs and spans?

The option value would be the address index of the array.

Comment: It would just be for display purposes only in the select list - so you could simply join every part of the address together separated by commas and make the select list wide enough to display the longest string.  The actual output, though, would be taken from the array, based on the index position, and populated into the appropriate places on the page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223576/discussion-between-defjamvan-and-atd).